# upgrade from magento 2.4.5 to magento 2.4.7 beta2 issue?

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-beta2 (exact version match), found magento/product-community-edition[0.42.0-beta7, 2.0.0, ..., 2.4.7-beta2] but it does not match the constraint

Comment: 2.*6*.7-beta2?  did you mean  2.*4*.7-beta2

Comment: Please suggest me some material how can i perform update

Comment: Please share the composer.json file here.